# How to find max in list?

Tags: python

I write the following code but it shows error.

```
a = [9,89,65,87]
print(max(a))
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>        in 
>         1 a = [9,89,65,87]
>       ----> 2 print(max(a))
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

How do I fix this or are there any documentation I need to read to get better understanding?

Comment: You have overwritten either `print` or `max`. Check which value they have!

Comment: Just run: `print(max)` and it should return like: `<built-in function max>` In this way you can identify whether you've overwritten `max()` method or not. If so, change the name print wherever you've used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that your `max` is not a function but an `int` object.

Can you just run the `print(max)` and check what exactly it is?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you used `max` or `print` as an integer variable name before, and the `max()` or `print()` function has been overwritten. Use another name for the variable that you called `max` or `print` previously and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**run**:

```
print(max)
```

And it should return like:

> built-in function max

In this way you can identify whether you've overwritten `max()` method or not. If so, change the name print wherever you've used.

Here are some links for your reference:

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/max.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/

Answer (score 0):

This code is working properly, so please check your code and run it again

```
>>> a = [9,89,65,87]
>>> print(max(a))
89
```